# Interpreting regression equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Interpreting notation in logarithmic transform. I have an equation of a regression line after a logarithmic transformation of variables.

$$\log10(x)=b+m\log10(y)$$

How am I supposed to interpret this formula ?

$$\log(10x)=b+m\log(10y)$$ or

$$x\log10=b+my\log10$$ or

$$\log_{10}(x)=b+m\log_{10}(y)$$ ?

Comment: The last one I guess...

Comment: give us more context? what is the equation before this formula.

Comment: I was given scatterplots and was attempting to transform data for a linear regression. The transform I am supposed to use is the logarithmic one. This is the form of the regression line after the data was transformed.Sorry, I am lost right now in elementary statistics so sorry if what I have said isn't stated correctly. And the problem statement was given using how the equation would be written in r I guess?

Comment: Generally "log" represents a base ten logarithm, "ln" refers to natural logarithm. "log10" is another way of writing "log", that eliminates any ambiguity. To write the logarithm of 10y, you would write "log 10y, log (10y)",  "log10 10y", or "log10(10y)".

Answer (score 1):

If you have $$\log_{10}x = b + m \log_{10} y$$

It means you believe that your function follows the form of

$$x= 10^b y^m$$

and you are trying to solve for $b$ and $m$.